# How to add new images to existing shortcode configuration?

Tags: shortcode, gallery

How would I go about adding/updating images and content to an existing gallery with established shortcode?

Not the most Wordpress savvy but I'd love to be able to make some changes to a site that features profiles of people. I have my site's existing shortcode but there doesn't seem to be an intuitive way to make these changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [WP Gallery Image Shortcode](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpgalleryimage-shortcode/) plugin. You will just have to add the wppgalleryimage shortcode. Then, you will have to specify the image you want to add by name or ID.